VSCode jump-to-definition in editable pip project location
I have an editable pip package in my project directory, which I installed by cloning a package from GitHub and running pip install --no-deps -e . from inside my-project/my-package.
Here are the relevant paths in the pip show my-package output:
Name: my-package
Location: <...>/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages
Editable project location: <...>/my-project/my-package

I am currently editing the package in my-project/my-package and simultaneously using it in other parts of my code in my-project, and when I ctrl+click on an object, I want to be taken to its definition inside of my-project/my-package so that I can continue working on it. Instead, Pylance takes me to the installed package location at <...>/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages. How can I avoid this? I keep editing it by accident while I'm working and it has no effect, I would very much like to be taken to my-project/my-package directly.
